# What are the coordinates of a fixed vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm stuck at the following thing:

In a 2D coordinate plane, where we have the origin O(0,0),  we are given, let's say the points A(2,4) and B(3,7). The coordinates of the vector AB is (3-2,7-4), which is (1,3). But here's my problem: shouldn't the coordinates of that vector actually be the points A,B, like this:
AB = (A,B) = (2,4; 3,7)?

What I want to say, is that if the vector AB = (1,3), how would I know were did it came from originally? Because originally the vector is way up between A(2,4) and B(3,7). Saying that AB = (1,3) moves it automatically to the origin, and the vector segment originally was not at the origin.

I really thank you!

Comment: Where to put the tail end of the vector is something on which different fields of mathematics and physics have differing conventions. Some say that all vectors should always have their tail at the origin of the coordinate grid, some say they can have their tail where the actual vector originated. In the end, it depends on your application. At any rate, they both agree that the vector $\vec {AB}$ should be an arrow that points one unit to the right and three units up (if you're using a standard coordinate grid).

Comment: To give a concrete example, if your vectors describe translations of the plane (i.e. "I'm going to slide the plane so that $A$ ends up at where $B$ is now, and I want a vector to describe this sliding motion"), then vectors are most naturally put with their tail at the origin. If you're describing the flow of a fluid in the plane, then the vector describing the flow at a given point should have its tail end at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally speaking, a vector has only two properties:

1. Magnitude
2. Direction

A given vector can have any initial point. Vectors in the plane can be "moved around" so long as neither their direction nor their magnitude changes.

The vector with initial point $(2,4)$ and terminal point $(3,7)$ is the *same vector* as the vector with initial point $(0,0)$ and terminal point $(1,3)$. They are sometimes referred to as two *representations* of the *same vector*.

The representation of a vector having initial point $(0,0)$ is sometimes call its *standard* representation, or a *standard* vector.